# Translation of "s.v." ("sub verbo" or "sub voce")

Tags: traducción, abreviaturas, latinismo

In a scholarly article in English, if you quote from a dictionary dictionary, your reference will typically say

> *(name of dictionary)*, s.v. "(word whose meaning was given)."

How should I do that in Spanish?  Should I also use "s.v." -- the same as in English?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the same form "s.v.'" or "s/v". For example:

> Más información en Wikipedia **s/v** Arte

I got that example from the [**sub voce** entry in wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub_voce), where they explain

> **Sub voce** (plural sub vocibus) es una locución latina que significa literalmente «bajo la voz» o «bajo la palabra». En español y otras lenguas se utiliza generalmente **abreviado como s. v. o s/v** para indicar que determinada información aparece como entrada en una obra de referencia que se organice de este modo, como un diccionario o una enciclopedia.

Comment: You may also quote the page [Abreviaturas](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/abreviaturas) from the RAE. In there, they accept both _s. v._ and _s/v_. Note though the space between _s._ and _v._.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally never seen such thing (or have never noticed). The thing is, I don't think it is a matter of the language, but a matter of the quotation system you are using for your essay/text/work, i.e. APA, MLA, etc.

Each of these will tell you how to do it according to their rules. Of course, be consistent through your whole text ;)

Comment: I didn't realize there's an APA or MLA for Spanish.  Can you point me to some easy to use style guides?

Comment: You can just google "resumen MLA", "resumen APA", etc. Of course, choose trustworthy sources (university domains, etc.) For example, this: http://www.eticaacademica.unam.mx/MLA_Resumen.pdf